Error using a custom transformer in an SKLearn pipeline, but not as a standalone transformer
As an exercise I'm trying to create a custom transformer that takes a dataset and labels and returns the transformed dataset keeping only those columns with a correlation with the labels above a certain threshold. The transformer is given by the following code:
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class CorrelatedAttributesKeeper(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, correlation_threshold = 0.5):
        self.correlation_threshold = correlation_threshold
        self.returned_indices = []    
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        correlations = []
        for col in X:
            correlations.append(np.corrcoef(X[col].to_numpy(), y.to_numpy())[0,1])
        for idx, x in enumerate(correlations):
            if x > self.correlation_threshold:
                self.returned_indices.append(idx)
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        return X.iloc[:, self.returned_indices]


The following seems to work as intended:
high_correl_transformer = CorrelatedAttributesKeeper(0.5)
transformed_housing_num = high_correl_transformer.fit_transform(housing_num, housing_labels) 

However, trying to run it as part of a pipeline errors off:
num_pipeline2 = Pipeline([
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy="median")),
    ('attribs_adder', CombinedAttributesAdder()),
    ('std_scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ('correl_keeper', CorrelatedAttributesKeeper()),])
housing_num_tr2 = num_pipeline.fit_transform(housing_num, housing_labels)


This produces the following error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in __PYTHON_EL_eval
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/tmp/babel-0JUX9y/python-okiPo8", line 6, in <module>
    housing_num_tr2 = num_pipeline.fit_transform(housing_num, housing_labels)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 1474, in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 543, in fit_transform
    return last_step.fit_transform(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_set_output.py", line 295, in wrapped
    data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 1101, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: CorrelatedAttributesKeeper.fit() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given


I'm struggling to understand the stack-trace. It states fit takes 1 positional argument, but it seems like it takes at least 3, both in my definition and at the bottom of the stack trace: self, X, and y. What am I not getting?
Thanks

I don't know what is causing the specific TypeError you've reported, but this answer addresses another problem with the class.
The steps preceding your custom transformer are returning numpy arrays, which would cause the custom transformer to error as it's expecting a pandas dataframe.
I was going to suggest using StandardScaler().set_output(transform='pandas') and SimpleImputer().set_output(transform='pandas') in order to configure them to return dataframes, however I think this would cause the other custom estimator to error, as it's expecting numpy arrays (I've referred to the github of the example you're working with).
You could change your custom transformer to work with numpy arrays. I've done that below, and it works when running:
make_pipeline(
    SimpleImputer(),
    StandardScaler(),
    CorrelatedAttributesKeeper()
).fit_transform(X, y)

I've also made some other changes to make it more aligned with the requirements of sklearn estimators. These changes include adding a trailing underscore to denote fitted attributes; defining self.n_features_in_; and not creating new variables inside __init__ (limit it to just storing the supplied arguments).
Modified class:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.utils import check_array, check_X_y

class CorrelatedAttributesKeeper(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, correlation_threshold=0.5):
        self.correlation_threshold = correlation_threshold
        
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        
        #To np if necessary, and checks
        X, y = check_X_y(X, y)
            
        self.n_features_in_ = X.shape[1]
        self.returned_indices_ = []
        
        correlations = []
        
        for col_idx in range(self.n_features_in_):
            correlations.append(np.corrcoef(X[:, col_idx], y)[0,1])
        
        for idx, x in enumerate(correlations):
            if x > self.correlation_threshold:
                self.returned_indices_.append(idx)
        
        return self
    
    def transform(self, X):
        X = check_array(X)
        return X[:, self.returned_indices_]


Data and tests:
#
#Test data
#
np.random.seed(0)
X = pd.DataFrame({
    'f0': np.linspace(0, 1, 100),
    'f1': np.linspace(0, 1, 100) + np.random.uniform(-0.4, .4, size=100),
    'f2': np.random.normal(size=100),
    'f3': np.random.normal(size=100),
})
y = pd.Series(np.linspace(0, 1, 100))

# Estimator should return f0 and f1, but not f2 or f3
display(
    'Correlation values',
    pd.concat([X, y.to_frame()], axis=1).corr().iloc[:-1, -1]
)

#Test separately
#with dataframes
CorrelatedAttributesKeeper().fit_transform(X, y)#.returned_indices_
#with numpy arrays
CorrelatedAttributesKeeper().fit_transform(X.values, y.values)#.returned_indices_

#Test in pipeline
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

make_pipeline(
    SimpleImputer(),
    StandardScaler(),
    CorrelatedAttributesKeeper()
).fit_transform(X, y)


This is a good point. But I don't see how it could give rise to the error in the question?

Good point. I've looked at this again and I can't trace the source of the original TypeError, so I've now clarified that my answer addresses another problem with the class.
